# Is BLS signature still conjectured to achieve $b$-bit security for $2b$-bit appendix?

Tags: signature, bls-signature

The BLS signature scheme [1] promised $b$-bit security for signature with a $2b$-bit appendix, under classical hypothesis leaving aside the possibility of Quantum Computers usable for cryptanalysis. Hovav Shacham's [2005 thesis](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/thesis-hyperref.pdf) proposed to use Barreto-Naehrig curves to achieve security comparable to RSA-1024 ($b\approx80$-bit security) with a $2b=160$-bit appendix.

However, per this [summary of 2016 attacks](http://curves.moderncrypto.narkive.com/zVqeZt0P/curves-for-pairings), BLS signature using BN curves turned out to require larger appendix; like perhaps $8b/3$-bit appendix for $b$-bit security with $b\approx128$ (with [Barreto?](https://ellipticnews.wordpress.com/2016/05/02/kim-barbulescu-variant-of-the-number-field-sieve-to-compute-discrete-logarithms-in-finite-fields/#li-comment-1176) and [Menezes-Palash-Singh](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/1102) considering $3b$-bit for something conservative).

---

Is BLS signature still conjectured to achieve $b$-bit security for $2b$-bit appendix using some concrete construction, and which? If not, what comes closest?

If that's not too much a different question, what would be a concrete parametrization for $b\approx128$-bit security?

---

[1] : Dan Boneh, Ben Lynn, Hovav Shacham, [*Short Signatures from the Weil Pairing*](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~hovav/dist/sigs.pdf), in [Journal of Cryptology, 2004](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00145-004-0314-9), originally in [proceedings of Asiacrypt 2001](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45682-1_30).

Comment: According to my reading of BLS, the way to do this would be to increase the "security multiplier" beyond 6. I'm not competely sure but I think the multiplier is half the embedding degree (BN curves have $d = 12$), in which case [eprint 2011/465](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/465) might be your answer as it suggests curves with $d = 24$.